# Ruby regex return match based on negation

Tags: ruby, regex

I just want to capture the part of the string in `nbnbaasd<sd` which appears before any `a`.

I want it to return `nbnb` as the match.

```
 /.+(?!a)/.match("nbnbaasd<sd") # returns the whole string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the whole string because indeed, "nbnbaasd<sd" is *not* followed by an "a".

Try this.

```
/.+?(?=a)/.match("nbnbaasd<sd")
```

(You do not actually need to use a lookahead to achieve this, but perhaps you've simplified your problem and in your real problem you do need a zero-width assertion for some reason.  So this is a solution as close as possible to the one you've attempted.)

Answer (score 5):

Just use a [negated character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
/[^a]+/.match("nbnbaasd<sd")
```

It's far more efficient than the look-ahead method.

---

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?32288